# Use of pumping lemma in case of language $0^n 1^m$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

It is known that language $0^n 1^m$ is regular whereas $0^n 1^n$ is not. But what if I pick string $0^p 1^p$ to proof irregularity of $0^n 1^m$ ? Here, $p$ is pumping constant. In this case, I can proof that $0^n 1^m$ is not regular. It looks to me weird but can't understand where I am wrong.

Comment: For your regular language $p=1$. The pumping lemma concerns words of sufficiently large length. Short words do not pump.

Comment: You cannot prove the irregularity of $0^n 1^m$, since it is regular. So your proof will fail. Try fleshing your proof out completely rather than leaving it in a vague outline, and you will see a mistake.

Comment: A regular set like $0^n1^m$ can contain an irregular subset like $0^n1^n$. Notice that $0^n1^n$ is also a subset of $(0+1)^*$, which is as regular as can be.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the string $0^p1^p$ doesn't change the predicate which defines the language. Since there is no requirement that the pumped string have the form $0^n1^n$, it's trivial to pump your chosen string; just choose one of the 0's as the substring to be pumped.